Handle HomePageLoad and reload in Symfony UX turbo
I have a Single Page Application in Symfony (UX) with a navigation sidebar. Clicking on a button in the sidebar loads a specific screen using Turbo frames. This actually works very neatly, the only issue I am encountering is the following:
When the user initially opens the app on the / route the whole twig for the app should be loaded including the navigation. After the load the user can successfully load other frames by using the navigation. But, what should I do when the user clicks the home-button in the navigation? I don't want to reload my whole app.
So, when the user initially loads the page my HomeDisplayController would render app.html.twig containing my navigation etc.
final class HomeDisplayController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_home', methods: ['GET'])]
    #[AuthRequired]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@web/app/app.html.twig');
    }
}

But when the app is loaded, I would actually like to only render @web/app/home.html.twig containing the content for home.
How would I handle this without having duplicate code? Should I make a service RenderHomePage to solve this issue?
Code:
HomeDisplayController
<?php

namespace App\UI\Http\Controller\AppScreen;

use App\UI\Http\Attribute\AuthRequired;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

final class HomeDisplayController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'app_home', methods: ['GET'])]
    #[AuthRequired]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@web/app/app.html.twig');
    }
}

app.html.twig
{% extends '@web/base.html.twig' %}

{% block script %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app2') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="app-container">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li id="nav-logo">
                <img alt="" src="{{ asset('media/images/nav/logo.png') }}">
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('app_home') }}" data-turbo-frame="screen">
                    <img alt="Home" src="{{ asset('media/images/nav/home.png') }}">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('app_children') }}" data-turbo-frame="screen">
                    <img alt="Children" src="{{ asset('media/images/nav/children.png') }}">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('app_orders') }}" data-turbo-frame="screen">
                    <img alt="Orders" src="{{ asset('media/images/nav/orders.png') }}">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ path('app_settings') }}" data-turbo-frame="screen">
                    <img alt="Settings" src="{{ asset('media/images/nav/settings.png') }}">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <turbo-frame id="screen"></turbo-frame>
</div>
{% endblock %}

ChildrenDisplayController
<?php

namespace App\UI\Http\Controller\AppScreen;

use App\UI\Http\Attribute\AuthRequired;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

final class ChildrenDisplayController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/app/children', name: 'app_children', methods: ['GET'])]
    #[AuthRequired]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@web/app/children.html.twig');
    }
}

children.html.twig
<turbo-frame id="screen">
    <h2>Children</h2>
</turbo-frame>

OrderDisplayController
<?php

namespace App\UI\Http\Controller\AppScreen;

use App\UI\Http\Attribute\AuthRequired;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;

final class OrdersDisplayController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/app/orders', name: 'app_orders', methods: ['GET'])]
    #[AuthRequired]
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@web/app/orders.html.twig');
    }
}

orders.html.twig
<turbo-frame id="screen">
    <h2>Food orders</h2>
</turbo-frame>

home.html.twig -> should contain content for hone
<turbo-frame id="screen">
    <h2>Home</h2>
</turbo-frame>


Why not, by default include home in your screen frame?

    {% include '@web/app/home.html.twig' %}
